# Node.js nested forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 arrays that I need to enter a multi-select one. 
The first loop is to print all categories, while the second loop must add "selected" only if present in the db.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple name="category" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <% categories.forEach(function (cat){ %>
      <% operation.category.forEach(function (key){ %>
          <option value="<%= cat._id %>" <% if(key == cat._id){ %>selected<% } %>><%= cat.name %></option>
      <% }); %>
   <% }); %>
</select>
```

The result:

```
 <select class="form-control" multiple name="category" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <option value="5316fff4542a276208095eb6" >Cat 1</option>
      <option value="5316fff4542a276208095eb6" >Cat 1</option>

      <option value="5316fc2170f952fb076e1fd5" >Cat 2</option>
      <option value="5316fc2170f952fb076e1fd5" >Cat 2</option>

      <option value="5316fc1a70f952fb076e1fd4" selected>Cat 3</option>
      <option value="5316fc1a70f952fb076e1fd4" >Cat 3</option>

      <option value="5316fc1170f952fb076e1fd3" >Cat 4</option>
      <option value="5316fc1170f952fb076e1fd3" selected>Cat 4</option>
```

Why are cloned?

Comment: Hint: The nested loop will output `categories.length * operation.category.length` option elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the whole `operation.category` list for each of the selected `categories`.

Instead, try this:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple name="category" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <% operation.category.forEach(function (key){ %>
      <option value="<%= cat._id %>"<% categories.forEach(function (cat){
         if(key == cat._id){ %> selected<% }
      }); %>><%= cat.name %></option>
   <% }); %>
</select>
```

Or even better

```
<select class="form-control" multiple name="category" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <% operation.category.forEach(function (key){ %>
      <option value="<%= cat._id %>"<%
         if (categories.some(function (cat){
            return key == cat._id;
         })) {
            %> selected<%
         }
      %>><%= cat.name %></option>
   <% }); %>
</select>
```

Comment: Which one? And what is the error? Check your log for exact error message.

Comment: TypeError: /vagrant/src/contonline/views/bill/edit.ejs:33
    31|
    32|                 <select class="form-control" multiple name="category" style="margin-top: 20px;">
 >> 33|                     <% categories.forEach(function (cat){ %>
    34|                     <option value="<%= cat._id %>" <%
    35|                     if (operation.category(function(key){
    36|                         return cat._id == key;

Property 'category' of object { name: 'Test',
  category: [ '53170c97f067c4b30994f929' ] } is not a function

Comment: You didn't use the `categories.some` method, but tried to call `operation.category()` - pretty obvious with that error message… Please use exactly the code from my answer